# Why is my /etc/apt/sources.list set to squeeze when I have debian wheezy?

Tags: debian, aptitude

I have set up a few new debian boxes which were installed with debian wheezy (7.1). I set them up and upgraded to the current stable release:

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
7.6
```

If I look at my `etc/apt/sources.list` which I haven't touched at all I get:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
```

The last two appear to be set to squeeze which I have not had installed on this box at all.

I would like to install certain packages from unstable so am looking to add the repos following [this guide](http://www.binarytides.com/enable-testing-repo-debian/).

I would also like to check I have the correct canonical form of the sources.list before changing it so was wondering whether what I have is correct or whether it should be changed. I have been unable to find a canonical answer to what the default sources.list for debian 7.4 should be (I tend to use arch personally and am quite new to debian).

Edit: reading [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#A.2Fetc.2Fapt.2Fsources.list) I am unsure of whether I shoud be using stable or wheezy as the variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Debian Wheezy, all of the entries should be `wheezy` or higher. Therefore, I recommend you change `squeeze` to `wheezy`.

After doing so, run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, as I would expect you have several security updates to install.

Comment: Just to check, I should change that part to `wheezy/updates` for both of the bottom lines. Should it be that rather than `stable/updates`? are the top 2 lines ok? I occasionally seem to get errors that seem to be 404s from the non-US mirror.

Comment: I believe it can be `stable` as well. You could change the non-US mirror to use `wheezy`, but I don't think it will make much of a difference.

Comment: Would you recommend using [this list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list_for_Debian_7_.22Wheezy.22) with contrib and free added? I'm just somewhat nervous about messing with it myself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As a better explanation, if you choose `stable`, you will be on whatever is considered "stable". This means when Jessie 8.0 is declared as stable, you will upgrade to Jessie. If you choose `wheezy` instead, you will be on `wheezy` packages only.

Comment: You mean [this](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list_for_Debian_7_.22Wheezy.22) link? Yes, that looks good. (It's Debian own wiki.)

Comment: Also, see [this](https://wiki.debian.org/non-US) page regarding the non-US errors.

Comment: perfect, thank you so much for helping me understand this.